# How to make selectable area of button smaller in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, user-interface, button

in Unity3D I have a button-object which has an image as a child. So far so good.

[image: Unity3D-GUI]

Now I would like to make the button's selectable area (hit-zone) smaller than the size of the child-image. Is that possible? I know it's possible to create a bigger hit-zone but don't know if it's possible when you want to decrease it.

Is there a script available which makes the hit-zone smaller than the child-image?

This script is attached to my button which swaps the image of the child (when hovering over) but the hit-zone still has the same size (which I want it to be smaller) than the child-image:

```
class BtnSwapImage : MonoBehaviour, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerEnterHandler
{
private Image image;
private Sprite imgPlayHover, imgPlay;
private Transform _obj;

void Start() {
    imgPlayHover = Resources.Load <Sprite>("GUI/gui_main_btnplayhover_720p");
    imgPlay = Resources.Load <Sprite>("GUI/gui_main_btnplay_720p");

    IterateChildren(this.transform);
}

void IterateChildren(Transform trans)
{
    // Debug.Log(trans.name); // Do whatever logic you want on child objects here
    if (trans.childCount == 0) return;

    foreach(Transform obj in trans)
    {
        if (obj.name == "Image") _obj = obj;
        IterateChildren(obj);
    }
}

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log ("OnPointerEnter");
    this._obj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = imgPlayHover;
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log ("OnPointerExit");
    this._obj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = imgPlay;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No script needed:

On the current images components of the button set [`RaycastTarget`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Image.html) to `false` so these are not considered as interaction area.

> Enable Raycast Target if you want Unity to consider the image a target for raycasting.

It's kind of as if you would disable it's collider.

Then simply add a new child image component that is fully transparent and on this one enable the `RaycastTarget` so this is the only Component for this button that now defines the interaction rect area according to it's scales in the rect transform.

This interactive one could also be the button itself which usually has already an `Image` component as well.

Comment: Ah. Thanks I will try this ASAP!:D

Comment: It works!:) Enabled RayCastTarget on the button and disabled RayCastTarget on the child-image! Thanks man you saved my day!:)